# Mathematics and cinema

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-science, applications, art

I wander if anyone of you have some knowledge about relations between abstract algebra and cinema. I'm not searching for movies about mathematics or algebra; I'm searching for some kind of application of algebra in the technical or aesthetic aspect of cinema itself. I would prefer an application of abstract algebra but applications of logic, analysis, topology or set theory also will be appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Fractals are widely used. See for example https://plus.maths.org/content/modelling-nature-fractals

Comment: [Disney Research](https://www.disneyresearch.com/publications/) might be a decent place to start.

Comment: Linear algebra, which is involved with CGI stuff, is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Not sure this entirely fits what is asked, but in case: http://www.nytimes.com/2010/12/30/movies/30animate.html

Comment: @ClementC. The [Discrete Differential Geometry](http://ddg.cs.columbia.edu/) stuff mentioned in that article is actually pretty cool stuff and one of the first things I thought of.  While not the usual groups and rings, it is an application of exterior algebra.

Comment: Math of CGI is very old, dating back to the 1970s.  The Foley-Van Dam book on graphics is a starting place.  http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Principles-Practice-Edition/dp/0321399528

Answer (score 1):

There is a separate ceremony of technical Oscar awards each year.  Some of the awards have been for theoretical works, including PhD theses, in computer science, physics and possibly mathematics.   A look through the lists may show something based on, or using somewhere, algebra beyond the linear algebra of matrices.

Some of the work in discrete differential geometry is directly motivated by computer graphics.  If you consider discrete integrable systems (commutative rings of difference operators) to be "abstract algebra" here is an example: http://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0979 .